# Java String.replaceAll with different match & replace criteria

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this code:

```
String polynomial = "2x^2-4x+16";
String input = polynomial.replaceAll("[0-9a-zA-Z][-]", "+-");
```

The problem is I don't want to actually replace the `[0-9a-zA-Z]` char.

Previously, I had used `polynomial.replace("-","+-");` but that gave incorrect output with negative powers.

The new criteria `[0-9a-zA-Z][-]` solves the negative power issue; however it replaces a char when I only need to insert the `+` before the `-` without deleting that char.

How can I replace this pattern using the char removed like:

```
polynomial.replaceAll("[0-9a-zA-Z][-]", c+"+-");
```

where 'c' represents that `[0-9a-zA-Z]` char.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Just give example input and output. All the info about your attempts is meaningless without context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use groups for this:

```
polynomial.replaceAll("([0-9a-zA-Z])[-]", "$1+-");
```

`$1` refers to the first thing in brackets.

[Java regex reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html :

There it says that backreferences are made by \1, \2 ... \n, not $1. I don't know that $1, ... won't work, but thought I'd mention it

Comment: @MadDogMcNamara `\1` is for group references *from inside* the regular expression while `$1` is for group references in `replace...` (following a few links from `String.replaceAll` gets you [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String))).